# Exception handling middleware doesn't handle exceptions - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware is called (ASP.NET Core WebAPI)

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, middleware

I created an exception handling middleware according to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
    
    // ...
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
[ApiController]
public class ErrorsController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("error")]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return Problem();
    }
}
```

Now let's say that I threw the following exception: `throw new Exception("BAX");`
My exception handling middleware catches this exception and works great. But the problem is that in console I see the following log:

> |ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware|An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.|System.Exception: BAX (stack trace goes here)

*Note*: I removed stack trace to make it a little bit shorter.

Maybe I should also say that I use `NLog` for logging. Here is the configuration of it:

```
<target xsi:
    type = "ColoredConsole" name = "colored_console"
    layout = "|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}|${exception:format=tostring}">
</target >
```

#### Question

My exception was caught by [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.exceptionhandlermiddleware?view=aspnetcore-5.0).
It looks like my exception handling middleware didn't handle the exception. Am I right?

My question is why it works so and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duty of `app.UseExceptionHandler("errors")` is `log` errors then redirect users to a page in order to show them a proper message.

**First of all**, when you have `app.UseExceptionHandler("errors")` it means, ASP.NET Core redirects to a controller named `errors` and according to your code, it won't work because your `Conroller` name is `Errors` and in your code you defined `error` as its path.

if you don't want `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` to be called, then you have to write your own middleware and log errors there. here is an example of custom middleware to catch all exceptions.

```
   public class CustomMiddlewareMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomMiddlewareMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
           
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {

            /// log it here and then redirect to spesific path
       
            if (httpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !httpContext.Response.HasStarted)
            {
                httpContext.Request.Path = "/error/404/";
                await _next(httpContext);
            }
        }
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my project I don't have `app.UseExceptionHandler("errors")` -I have `app.UseExceptionHandler("error")`, so because of this it works great. 

But why to create a middleware instead of exception filter?

Comment: in your question, you have this `  app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");` and your controller name is `errors`, these are not same

Comment: `ErrorsController` doesn't have any route. Route `/error` is a route to the action method of this controller. As you can see, there is an action method called `Error` inside of this controller. This action method has the following attribute above: `[Route("error")]`

Comment: But again, I want to know, why I should use a middleware instead of exception filter in this situation?

Comment: in your comment you said, how can we avoid calling `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`, I thought you might want to have your own middleware.